# Free group and commutator question from Artin's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, problem-solving, free-groups

Let $F$ be the free group on $x$, $y$ and $R$ be the smallest normal subgroup containing the commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.

a) Show that $x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}$ is in $R$.

b) Prove that $R$ is the commutator subgroup of $F$.

I tried to conjugate $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ with some element in $F$ to get $x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}$ but failed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R$ is the smallest "normal" subgroup containing $[x,y]$. Then in $G/R$ the images of $x$ and $y$ will commute, i.e. $G/R$ is abelian, i.e. $G'\subseteq R$. On the other hand, by definition of $R$, it is clear that $R\subseteq G'$.

a) can be solved with the help of b): in $G/R$ the element $x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}$ goes to identity, hence it is in $G'=R$.

The other way: we write $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. Then 
$$x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}=x.(xy^2x^{-1}).x^{-1}y^2=x.(xy^2x^{-1}y^{-2}).y^2.x^{-1}y^2$$ 
$$=x.[x,y^2].y^2x^{-1}y^{-2}=x.[x,y^2].y^2x^{-1}y^{-2}x.x^{-1}=x.[x,y^2].[y^2,x^{-1}]x^{-1}$$
The last expression is conjugate of product of two commutators. It is sufficient to show that these two commutators are in $R$. You may try this easier computation than the original.

Comment: Hi Groups, thanks a lot for your answer. I am not clear about "R is the smallest "normal" subgroup containing [x,y]. Then in G/R the images of x and y will commute". Why commute?

Comment: I found group $G=<x, y; xyx^{-1}y^{-1}>$ is called a free abelian group, that make $G/R$ abelian.

Answer (score 1):

**a)**

$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in R$

$xyx^{-1}\in Ry=yR$

$y^{-1}xyx^{-1}\in R$

denote as *closed word*, in Chinese we could call it "回文"

\begin{gathered}
\begin{matrix}  &x& \\ y && y^{-1}\\&x^{-1}& \end{matrix}
\quad
\end{gathered}

read counterclockwise. cut from different place we could get a conjugation class

$(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)(y^{-1}xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})(yx^{-1}y^{-1}x)\in R$

$x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{2}y^{2}x^{-2}y^{-1}x\in R$

$x^{2}y^{2}x^{-2}y^{-1}x\in yxR=Ryx$

$x^{2}y^{2}x^{-2}y^{-2}\in Ryxx^{-1}y^{-1}=R$

**b)**

$(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^{-1}=yxy^{-1}x^{-1}\in R$

\begin{gathered}
\begin{matrix}  &x& \\ y && y^{-1}\\&x^{-1}& \end{matrix}
\quad
\end{gathered}

read clockwise. we get another conjugation class

we can get the results here, but can go further, too

$[xy,y]=xyyy^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in R$

it means that we could replace $x$ as $xy$, the commutator will still be in $R$

$[yx,y]=y(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})y^{-1}\in yRy^{-1}=R$

the same as $[x,xy],[x,yx]$

it implies that $R$ contains all commutators of $F$

thus we complete the proof